# "Number of elementes(256) differs from declaration(65536)" Migration D2007 to XE8

Tags: delphi, unicode

I am in the process of migrating code from D2007 to XE8.  I have a function that uses this data construct:

```
Map: array[Char] of Byte = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 62, 0, 0, 0, 63, 52, 53,
  54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2,
  ..............
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0);
```

Here is how it is used (S is a String):

```
I := Map[S[1]] + (Map[S[2]] shl 6);
```

When I try to compile with XE8 I get message

> **Number of elementes(256) differs from declaration(65536)**

What do I have to do to get it compile and work with XE8?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a consequence of the Unicode introduction in Delphi 2009. You can fix the issue by replacing `Char` by `AnsiChar`, or by adding 65 280 new entries to the array.

In the first case, you should also notice that you should let `S` be an `AnsiString`, and not a (Unicode) `string`; otherwise you might access e.g. `Map[chr(3653)]` which does not exist.

Comment: Neither of those options are likely to make the code work correctly.

Comment: @David: The second option was a joke. If the first option will work or not depends on what the OP is doing with the array.

Comment: First option won't work because `S` is a string. Which is now UTF-16 encoded. Asker seems happy.

Comment: @David: You are very right; I've updated my answer to address that issue.

Comment: Not that `S[3653]` doesn't exist. Rather that `Map[S[i]]` would not compile if `S[i]` were `WideChar`.

Answer (score 7):

`char` is an alias to a character type. In pre Unicode Delphi `char` is an alias to the 8 bit `AnsiChar` type. In Unicode Delphi it is an alias to the 16 bit `WideChar` type. That explains the compilation error.

Perhaps you actually have binary data. In which case you should stop using strings and use byte arrays. Instead of `char` use `byte`. Instead of string use `TBytes`, an alias for `TArray<byte>`, a dynamic array of byte. The problem with using string data types to hold binary data is that strings are subject to encoding conversions. Binary data needs to be held in binary data types.

Comment: A great related article explaining why Unicode is so important for modern computing... and this was from 2003... http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Or in general understanding string encoding.